# POSTGRESQL: How to run calculations for different dates

Tags: postgresql, date, time, subquery, series

I am trying to find out active users (grouped by age) for each month. I tried with subquery but i get an error. Is there decent way to do this? Thanks!

```
with first_date_of_month as
(
SELECT current_date - (interval '1 month' * s.a) AS dates FROM 
generate_series(0,24,1) AS s(a)
)


select q1.dates from first_date_of_month
where exists (select 
case when round ((CURRENT_DATE - date_of_birth)/365) =<18 then '0-18'
     ...
     when round ((CURRENT_DATE - date_of_birth)/365) >= 65 then '65+'
     Else 'N/A' end as "Age",
     count(1)
from users
and signup_date between q1.dates-INTERVAL '2 months' and q1.dates
group by 1 order by 1) ;
```

Comment: Your query makes no sense at all.  Try showing sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

First, `generate_series()` can work with timestamps:

```
test=# select * from generate_series('2017-01-01', now(), interval '1 month');
    generate_series
------------------------
 2017-01-01 00:00:00+00
 2017-02-01 00:00:00+00
 2017-03-01 00:00:00+00
 2017-04-01 00:00:00+00
 2017-05-01 00:00:00+00
 2017-06-01 00:00:00+00
 2017-07-01 00:00:00+00
(7 rows)
```

Second, there is a special function to get ages, it's surprisingly called `age()` and returns intervals:

```
test=# select age(now(), '1981-11-18');
                   age
-----------------------------------------
 35 years 7 mons 26 days 03:07:41.561932
```

Next, you can extract years from intervals, with `extract()`:

```
test=# select extract(year from age(now(), '1981-11-18'));
 date_part
-----------
        35
(1 row)
```

Finally, as far as I understand, you want to get counts of users grouped by age withing each month -- so this looks like you need 2 levels of grouping.

As a result, we get this (I use multiple CTE stages here, implicit CROSS JOIN at the 2nd CTE stage and finally, I reduce the number of "age" groups as you wanted in the main CTE query, when groups with "raw" ages are already obtained):

```
with dates(month) as (
  select generate_series(
    date_trunc('day', now() - interval '2 year'),
    now(), interval '1 month'
  )
), usrs_full_age as (
  select
    month,
    extract(year from age(now(), date_of_birth)) as age,
    count(*) as count
  from users u, dates
  where signup_date between month - interval '2 month' and month
  group by 1, 2
)
select
  month::date,
  case
    when age <= 18 then '0-18'
    -- ...
    else 'N/A' -- NULLs will go here (records with empty date_of_birth)
  end as age,
  sum(count) as count
from usrs_full_age
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2
;
```